# MediaPlayer for WinPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, fileopenpicker

I'm trying to create some mediaplayer, but stacked on this moment. Need to add some files to my playlist, but it throw an exception... Here's code

```
private async void Open_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker
            {
                ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
            };
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            var selectedFiles = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
            if (selectedFiles != null)
            {
                foreach (StorageFile file in selectedFiles)
                {
                    Playlist.Add(file.Path);
                }
            }

        }
```

The exception

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MediaPlayer.exe but was not handled in user code Additional information: The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: this code var selectedFiles = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync(); and ex An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MediaPlayer.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)

Comment: "The request is not supported" - sounds like you can't open a file picker.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.pickmultiplefilesasync.aspx) `FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync` is not implemented in Windows Phone 8 API, you need at least Windows 10 to be able to use it.

Comment: maybe you know some methods to open multiple files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [`FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.pickmultiplefilesasync.aspx) is not implemented in Windows Phone 8 API, you need at least Windows 10 to be able to use it.

> Requirements (Windows 8.x and Windows Phone 8.x)
>   Minimum supported phone: None supported